# convert an image to a txt file in triple comma separated RGB

Tags: python, arrays, image

In Python, how we can convert a .jpg file to a text file with triple comma-separated values of RGB, where these triples are separated by one space. For example:

```
0,0,200 0,0,10 10,0,0
90,90,50 90,90,10 255,255,255
100,100,88 80,80,80 15,75,255
```

The above is an image represented by 3x3 pixels. For each pixel the Blue, Green and Red values are provided, separated by commas. The top left pixel has (Blue=0,Green=0,Red=200). The top-right pixel has (Blue=10,Green=0,Red=0). The bottom-right pixel has (Blue=15,Green=75,Red=255). The bottom-left pixel has (Blue=100,Green=100, Red=88).

I could print out each pixel in a new line using the following code:

```py
import cv2
img = imread('myimage.png')
for i in img:
    for j in i:
        print(*j,sep=',')
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`print()` has an arg to change default ending from `\n`. And then you can print a newline at the end of every row of pixels.

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
for i in img:
    for j in i:
        print(*j, sep=',', end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Alternatively, since you want to write to file, you could use list comprehension and string formatting to get each row in the desired pattern and then add a newline. 

`with open('mytest.jpg', 'w') as f_out:
    for i in img:
        f_out.write(' '.join(['{},{},{}'.format(*j) for j in i]) + '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code solved my problem, thanks to [user3474165](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3474165/user3474165):

```py
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('.').joinpath('images') # you shoud adjust this address upon your need
img = cv2.imread(path.joinpath('image_name')) # you should change 'image_name' upon your need
with open(path.joinpath('output.txt'), 'w') as f_out: # you should change 'output.txt' upon your need
    for i in img: 
        f_out.write(' '.join(['{},{},{}'.format(*j) for j in i]) + '\n')
```